# Regarding Flume file name

Tags: flume

I am placing text files in spool direcotry.
I want to place in HDFS with the same names as source file names.

I used %{file} for prefix but it is giving full path of filename.But I dont want absolutepath,want only filename.

Regards,
KSReddy

Comment: Maybe you could paste your Flume configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a parameter for spooldir which adds a header which is false by default.

> agentname.sources.sourcename.fileHeader=true